# How do I fill an ImageDraw rectangle (or ellipse) color with a color from cm.ScalarMappable colormap data?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, colormap

I have some dataframe and I am constructing a layout of rectangles based on the x,y, dimension and data values from the dataframe, as follows:

```
import PIL.Image as Image, ImageDraw
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

data={'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
 'ratio': {0: 726242000000,1: 56200692307, 2: 146376666666,3: 143607000000},
 'x': {0: 750, 1: 2250, 2: 750, 3: 2250},
 'y': {0: 750, 1: 750, 2: 2250,3: 2250},
 'dimension': {0: 350, 1: 350, 2: 350, 3: 350}}
data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
minima = min(data.loc[:,'ratio'])
maxima = max(data.loc[:,'ratio'])
norm_ = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=minima, vmax=maxima, clip=True)
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=None, cmap=cm.tab20b)

image = Image.new('RGBA', (3000,3000), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    x0= (data.loc[index,'x']-data.loc[index,'dimension']/2)
    y0= (data.loc[index,'y']-data.loc[index,'dimension']/2)
    x1= (data.loc[index,'x']+data.loc[index,'dimension']/2)
    y1= (data.loc[index,'y']+data.loc[index,'dimension']/2)
    draw.rectangle((x0,y0,x1,y1),fill=mapper.to_rgba(data.loc[index,'ratio']))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

So how do I convert the cmap color data to be used to fill the rectangles?

Comment: The error is arriving from the "...fill=mapper.to_rgba(...)" part since it expects a rgba value from 0 to 255. How do I correctly map the colormap values to 0 to 255 rgba values?

Comment: Ok, so what is the `type` of the `mapper.to_rgba()` and how does it look?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I might have asked this question too soon and I found an answer to it:

The "bytes" in `mapper.to_rgba(data.loc[index,'ratio'],bytes=True)` is to be set `True` and I had the `norm` in `cm.ScalarMappable(norm=None, cmap=cm.tab20b)` accidentally set `None` which it should be `cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm_, cmap=cm.tab20b)`